# python insert to table gives type error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, list

I have a code where i cannot able to insert to the database,i need to even insert blank spaces or nil to the databse if found in list:
Please help me to insert all the values in the list to the databse!

```
qw=[]
with open('qwe.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:            
        matches = []
        for word in line.split():
            if word in keywords:
                matches.append(word)            
        if matches:

            ab= ' '.join(matches)
            qw.append(ab)    
        else:
            a1= 'nil'

            qw.append(a1)
print qw
for name in qw:
       cursor.execute(
       '''INSERT INTO Detail1 (Names)
          VALUES (%s, %s)''',
         (name))
```

But i get the error as:

```
>>> 
['bike car', 'nil', 'car', 'car bike car', 'nil', 'bike']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\syram1.py", line 45, in <module>
    (name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 184, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>>
```

Please help!Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: in that execute statement you have `%s` twice, but you only specify one argument (`name`)...

Answer (score 2):

The insert statement mentions only one column name and you are passing two arguments

```
'''INSERT INTO Detail1 (Names)
          VALUES (%s, %s)'''
```

So you need to try this:

```
'''INSERT INTO Detail1 (Names)
          VALUES (%s)'''
```

or mention the name of the second column of Detail1 table

```
'''INSERT INTO Detail1 (Names,SecondColumnName)
          VALUES (%s, %s)'''
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two times a %s in your format string, that means you should have two variables in the "( )" after the format string.